# Can I give luggage to friend during transit?

Tags: visas, transit, luggage

I have Pakistani citizenship and will be traveling from Pakistan to Brunei with a layover at Malaysia. I'll arrive at Malaysia at 2.30am and the next flight would be at 9.45pm the same day.

I'll be coming back to Malaysia around the 20th of June for my PhD, but I haven't obtained my student visa yet. I have however already obtained the visa acceptance letter (VAL). I'll be applying for a student visa in Brunei as soon as I arrive.

Can I leave some of my luggage in Malaysia while I'm in transit or would I need a visa for that? I have a brother in Malaysia who's studying at a local university; he'll pick it up from me. The reason is that they're mostly books and I'd just be bringing them back again from Brunei.

Comment: Your question is basically _can a Pakistani citizen exit airport immigration control in Malaysia without a visa_? Is your baggage going to be checked or carry on?

Comment: Could you mail it to your brother ahead of time instead?

Comment: @sirjonsnow I'm sorry but this is not possible. I was thinking of saving on costs and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a general rule in almost every airport that, to meet anyone during transit flight, you need to go to arrivals area; for that you need to obtain transit visa.

Because you have more than 12 hours of layover, you can apply for transit visa on arrival or [Transit without visa](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/ind_new-delhi/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-without-visa):

> 1. TWOV facility is offered only to Indian Sub Continental Countries citizens.
> 2. TWOV cannot be given to visitors who do not possess visa from 3rd country of destination as follows:
>
> Australia; New Zealand, United States of America, Japan, China,
>   Taiwan, South Korea
>
> 3. TWOV facility cannot exceed more than 120 hours (5 days).
> 4. TWOV facility is not available at entry point other than Kuala Lumpur International Airport (KLIA) and Kuala Lumpur International Airport 2 (KLIA2)
> 5. TWOV cannot be offered to passenger sponsored by airlines other than Malaysia Airlines, Air Asia and Malindo Air. At present only these 3 airlines have agreed and accepted all terms and conditions imposed by the Malaysian Government.
> 6. TWOV cannot be given to visitors who do not meet the following requirement:
>
> Valid national passport or internationally recognized travel
>   document;  Travel documents valid for more than six (6) months from
>   the date of entry;  A return ticket to country of origin;  Not listed
>   in the Immigration Department’s suspected list.
>
> 7. There will be no extension of TWOV facility.
> 8. Permanent resident and long term pass holder are not bound to any of the TWOV regulations and condition stipulated above.
> 9. TWOV will be issued free of charge at the Visa on Arrival counter at the immigration clearance upon arrival.

Indian Sub Continent countries listed are Sri Lanka, India, Bangadesh, Pakistan on the [klia2 info](http://www.klia2.info/trips/malaysia/malaysia-visa-information) page.

Leaving you belongings there might not be ideal, as you wouldn't want to risk getting your student visa.

Comment: Kindly provide direct quotes from your references in your answer instead of just a link. Links sometimes get lost when the page is moved.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie, thanks, updated the answer.

Comment: Will I have to do anything before I fly or should I just inquire about it there?

Comment: @KhalidHussain, as mentioned in Criteria & Conditions for transit without visa shows you are eligible for transit visa on arrival, as long as you have a proof of next flight and valid visa to travel for your destination country, for more detail about lasest and accorate info what documents you need to keep with you, just visit immigration official website.

Comment: Note that this answer was from an unofficial source, obviously Sheik Paul who usually does not even bother with sources won't point that out for you. Finding an official source is a bit of a problem, though, I believe  http://www.kln.gov.my/web/ind_new-delhi/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-without-visa is the newest. In particular, Malindo Air was missing (and so was 7,8,9). This is why you should never use unofficial sources -- it's outdated. I copied this version into the answer.